# Javascript: Assignment of the return of the function to the variable

Tags: javascript

I work on the project that I need to take the data input in the search box and pass it to API. I have built the function

```
function searchRef(){
  const inputValue = searchIp.value;
  return inputValue
}

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', searchRef)
```

and I want to assign inputValue to the variable, i.e `let input= searchRef()`

Regretfully, it does not work. What am I doing wrong?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You make use of the arrow function to achieve that:

```js
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{ let input = searchRef() });
```

You can assign that `input` value to anything else you want or create a separate function all together.